# How can I disable lazy loading of active record queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to query some objects from the database using a WHERE clause similar to the following:

```
@monuments =  Monument.where("... lots of SQL ...").limit(6)
```

Later on, in my view I use methods like `@monuments.first`, then I loop through `@monuments`, then I display `@monuments.count`.

When I look at the Rails console, I see that Rails queries the database multiple times, first with a limit of 1 (for `@monuments.first`), then with a limit of 6 (for looping through all of them), and finally it issues a count() query.

How can I tell ActiveRecord to only execute the query once? Just executing the query once with a limit of 6 should be enough to get all the data I need. Since the query is slow (80ms), repeating it costs a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation you'll want to trigger the query before you your call to `first` because while `first` is a method on `Array`, it's also a “finder method” on ActiveRecord objects that'll fetch the first record.

You can prompt this with any method that requires data to work with. I prefer using `to_a` since it's clear that we'll be dealing with an array after:

```
@moments = Moment.where(foo: true).to_a
# SQL Query Executed
@moments.first #=> (Array#first) <Moment @foo=true>
@moments.count #=> (Array#count) 42
```

In this case, you can also use `first(6)` in place of `limit(6)`, which will also trigger the query. It may be less obvious to another developer on your team that this is intentional, however.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `@monuments.first` should not hit the db, I confirmed it on my console, maybe you have multiple instance with same variable or you are doing something else(which you haven't shared here), share the exact code and query and we might debug.

Since, `ActiveRecord Collections` acts as array, you can use array analogies to avoid querying the db.

Regarding `first` you can do,

```
@monuments[0]
```

Regarding the `count`, yes, it is a different query which hits the db, to avoid it you can use `length` as..

```
@monuments.length
```

Comment: There's a lot of conjecture here that doesn't hold water. You may want to review the excellent [Rails Guide to ActiveRecord Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: I may not have been able to explain better but I am pretty sure the `where` query of the type asked by OP gets executed even without `.to_a` and `.first` doesn't hit db. Infact using `.to_a` has few drawbacks firstly, you can't execute scoped queries or any other method related to AR when you convert to array..secondly, as mentioned by you it confuses the devs later. Thirdly, `.count` hits the db not because it was not executed in first place but it is a scoped query and changes the definition of the actual query i.e. `@monuments`..

Comment: I would appreciate if you can come up with an example where a query is not executed first but after `to_a` and when `.first` is appended it hits the db again..

Comment: 1) `where` doesn't trigger queries. It just doesn't. It's not a finder method. 2) I said `to_a` is less confusing — it's deliberate and explicit. 3) The OP is done applying additional scopes to the AST at this point and can get all of the data he needs from a single query; given the performance impact, he's trying to avoid multiple hits. Chaining and running separate queries is against the point.